# How to automatically set IsSelected on a GridViewItem?

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview, user-controls, microsoft-metro

I have a list with objects that have all a property: IsSelected. Now I try to automatically select the items in a GridView if the property is true.

I tried to override PrepareContainerForItemOverride in the GridView and set a binding to the objects with no success. Any ideas?

```
protected override void PrepareContainerForItemOverride(DependencyObject element, object item)
{
    base.PrepareContainerForItemOverride(element, item);

    var listItem = element as GridViewItem;
    var binding = new Binding 
    {
        Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay, 
        Source = item, 
        Path = new PropertyPath("Selected")
    };
    if (listItem != null) 
        listItem.SetBinding(SelectorItem.IsSelectedProperty, binding);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was so close. I just have to set:

```
protected override void PrepareContainerForItemOverride(DependencyObject element, object item)
{
    base.PrepareContainerForItemOverride(element, item);

    var listItem = element as GridViewItem;
    listItem.IsSelected = true;
}
```

..to select all Items.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [ListViewExtensions](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/0657c67a93d5#WinRTXamlToolkit/Controls/Extensions/ListViewExtensions.cs).BindnableSelection from the WinRT XAML Toolkit, which allows you to bind to a list that is a subset of your GridView's ItemsSource and that contains items that you want selected.

Comment: Sadly, the Extensions don't work any more with WinRT 8.1

Comment: Really? What's broken?

Comment: I tried binding SelectedItems in GridView and it didn't work.

Comment: I must apologize and I'm surprised that it's working now. I have to use an initialized ObservableCollection, then everything is good.

Comment: Btw: Filip, thanks for your great effort on the WinRT XAML Toolkit. It makes creating store apps with MVVM a lot easier.

Comment: If it doesn't work without an initialized collection them it might be a bug in the toolkit.